# Postman set variable

Tags: variables, set, postman

Here is my example, I need to set values to the environment variable as follows
I have already known variable called 'ponumberA', is it possible to set that value to environment variable using 'pm.environment.set' function.

```
(((var ponumberA="A1234";
    pm.environment.set("ponumberxx",ponumberA);
    var ponumberxxx=pm.variables.get("ponumberxx")
    console.log ("Request PO # is  " +ponumberxxx))))
```

Comment: What's your actual problem? I see nothing wrong, except redundant `()`

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 , I defined this variable at 'Pre-RequestScript' (Ex: pm.environment.set("ponumberxx",ponumberA);)  level on collection. Can I use the variable ( ponumberxx) as a parameter of Get Request URL.

Comment: Yes, of course. To get variable in Postman UI, use syntax `{{variable_name}}`, like `{{ponumberxx}}`. To get variable in Postman script (Pre-request and Test) use `pm.variables.get("ponumberxx")`

Answer (score 1):

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/

you can set variable and scope from pm object

```
pm.environment.set
pm.collectionVariables.set
pm.variables.set
pm.globals.set
```

you can use this variables in any session like url , body ,header etc as

```
{{variablename}}
```

example

```
pm.environment.set("myvar",2)
```

and in url

```
https://www.somewebsite.com?id={{myvar}}
```